# SP.ClientContext on host web failed because of Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Tags: sharepoint, cross-domain, cors, sharepoint-2013, angularjs-http

I have a problem with a SharePoint-Hosted App (App for SharePoint) developed by me.
SharePoint version is 2013.

The app web is: `http://app-12a34567bcde8f.sharepoint.local/sites/DEV/HelloWorld`
The host url is: `http://dev.local/sites/DEV`

The example script is written in **JSOM**:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://dev.local/sites/DEV');
var contextSite = clientContext.get_site();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(e) {
    console.log('Success', e);
}, function(e) {
    console.log('Error', e);
});
```

**Info messages in console.**

```
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://dev.local/sites/DEV/_api/contextinfo required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for http://dev.local/sites/DEV/_api/contextinfo required CORS preflight.
```

**Error message in console.**

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

**Console.Log result:**

```
"Error"
[object Object] {$1C_0: true, $1F_0: Object {...}, $1o_0: null, $1p_0: null, $1r_0: Object {...}, $1u_0: null, $1X_0: false, $29_0: "Javascript ...", $2A_0: null, $2I_0: false, $2N_0: 180000, $2T_0: null, $8_0: null, $F_0: Object {...}, $F_1: null, $N_1: Object {...}, $v_0: null, $w_0: "http://dev...", $x_0: null}
```

I can't understand this, because the method with REST and SP.RequestExecutor doesn't work, too.
`-1003 App Web is not deployed for this app's request url http://dev.local.`

**Example:**

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor('http://dev.local');
executor.executeAsync({
    url: "http://dev.local/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refinementfilters='contenttype:equals (\"SPFolder\")'",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: 'application/json; odata=verbose',
    success: function(a) {
        console.log('Finish', a);
    },
    error: function(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log('Error', data, errorCode, errorMessage);
    }
});
```

**And jQuery said "401 UNAUTHORIZED":**

```
$.ajax({
    crosDomain: true,
    url: "http://dev.local/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&refinementfilters='contenttype:equals (\"SPFolder\")'",
    success: function(e) {
        console.log('Success', e);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log('Error', e);
    }, dataType:'json'
});
```

I want only execute one search query and use the SP.ClientContext normally.

*Thanks in Advance for any help!*

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: [Access SharePoint 2013 data from add-ins using the cross-domain library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx). Alternatively, you might try to set [Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html) on the IIS that hosts dev.local/sites/DEV.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory (Cross Domain) to get my query to work.  There is an example on this site.
[Explain when to use WebRequestExecutorFactory & SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5baeb648-a050-4df7-8dfc-c1144e9f14fd/explain-when-to-use-webrequestexecutorfactory-spproxywebrequestexecutorfactory?forum=sharepointdevelopment)